# Count of previously smaller elements encountered in an input stream of integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Given an input stream of numbers ranging from 1 to 10^5 (non-repeating) we need to be able to tell at each point how many numbers smaller than this have been previously encountered.

I tried to use the set in C++ to maintain the elements already encountered and then taking `upper_bound` on the set for the current number. But `upper_bound` gives me the iterator of the element and then again I have to iterate through the set or use `std::distance` which is again linear in time.

Can I maintain some other data structure or follow some other algorithm in order to achieve this task more efficiently?

**EDIT** : Found an older question related to fenwick trees that is helpful here. Btw I have solved this problem now using segment trees taking hints from @doynax comment.

[How to use Binary Indexed tree to count the number of elements that is smaller than the value at index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234399/how-to-use-binary-indexed-tree-to-count-the-number-of-elements-that-is-smaller-t)

Comment: Keep your table sorted at each time and use binary search. That's my first thought

Comment: How many elements in the stream?

Comment: my first thought is that: while you go through the list, generate a list where the numbers a sorted. Then show between which to numbers your current number fits and while that count your moves

Comment: @Alan stokes As the elements are non-repeating and less than 10^5 so 10^5 elements.

Comment: `we need to be able to tell at each point` does this mean every time an element is inserted?

Comment: @vishalic not that it maters at all for solving the problem, but the number of elements in the stream does ***not*** have to be 10^5.  Consider this stream: { 0, 1, 2, 1000000 }.

Comment: @ Marco A. yes at every time an element is inserted (or received).

Comment: @ Mike Nakis I was taking the worst case.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [Fenwick tree](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8917&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to me.

Comment: @doynax I was thinking of the same and wondering if that could work efficiently in this case

Comment: @ doynax I will need to learn about fenwick tree btw thanks for the link. Can you give me some direction now on how to think/approach on this so that I can refer to it after learning about fenwick tree.

Comment: @Marco A.: I don't see why not. If the size of the input set is of the same order-of-magnitude as the limit then just store the 100k-element array. Otherwise sparsely allocate tree branches as needed, it shouldn't affect the complexity.

Comment: Here is an introduction to Fenwick tree: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-%20trees/

Comment: @doynax Read about segment trees a bit and got the idea somewhat. We  will initialize an array with 0.As we are encountering an element we will use point update to update the frequency of the element in the array(just like a map).And do a range sum query for (1,current number -1 ) to find how many elements I have encountered smaller than this number.Is this correct??

Comment: @vishallc: Essentially. The idea is that you create a binary tree from the 100,000 possible slots, where the parent nodes store the values of itself and all of its children so you can update/compute the value of a single node by walking to the root. Except instead of managing a balanced binary tree you form an implicit tree inside of an array, much like a heap does, based on the binary representation of the values. More or less. I suggest you read the paper for the details since it is surprisingly short and readable without the usual formalisms. How sparse is your data set?

Comment: @doynax Please post your excellent answer as an answer.

Comment: vishalic, if this is solved, please don't forget to accept an answer (or post your own answer and accept it), and upvote any answers you found helpful.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I will post my own answer soon on the lines of doynax comments as I am still getting the hang of fenwick tree.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the container you are using, it is very good idea to enter them as sorted set so at any point we can just get the element index or iterator to know how many elements are before it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your table sorted at each step. Use binary search. At each point, when you are searching  for the number that was just given to you by the input stream, binary search is going to find either the next greatest number, or the next smallest one. Using the comparison, you can find the current input's index, and its index will be the numbers that are less than the current one. This algorithm takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: Only answer so far to actually specify complexity.

Comment: However: insert into a sorted array is O(N), so I think the true complexity of your algorithm is O(N ^ 2).

Comment: We can insert the element by using  binary search since the table has unique elements.

Comment: You can find the insertion point in log time. But then to make space to do the insert you have to move half the elements on average giving linear time.

Comment: Of course, I'm dumb. I'll fix this immediately. This can be narrowed down to O(n*lgn) by using an appropriate data structure, though. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own binary search tree algorithm. Each node should store two counters with total number of its child nodes.

Insertion to binary tree takes `O(log n)`. During the insertion counters of all parents of that new element should be incremented `O(log n)`.

Number of elements that are smaller than the new element can be derived from stored counters `O(log n)`.

So, total running time `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Suppose we are given an sorted array as the input then these O(log n) steps will be converted to O(n).A std::set (self balancing binary search tree) will never let this happen.The worst case is O(n^2).But this might work for other cases.

Comment: @vishallc It is true for not balanced tree. However, self balanced trees should give `O(log n)`. Actually that trick with counters is used in self-balanced trees to rearange tree in `O(log n)` time during insertion.

Comment: @vishallc BTW, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree "Applications: Self-balancing BSTs are flexible data structures, in that it's easy to extend them to efficiently record additional information or perform new operations. For example, one can record the number of nodes in each subtree having a certain property, allowing one to count the number of nodes in a certain key range with that property in O(log n) time."

Answer (score 0):

What if you used insertion sort to store each number into a linked list? Then you can count the number of elements less than the new one when finding where to put it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to use `std` or not. In *certain situations*, some parts of `std` are inefficient. (For example, `std::vector` can be considered inefficient in *some* cases due to the amount of dynamic allocation that occurs.) It's a case-by-case type of thing.

One possible solution here might be to use a **skip list** (relative of linked lists), as it is easier and more efficient to insert an element into a skip list than into an array.

You have to use the skip list approach, so you can use a binary search to insert each new element. (One cannot use binary search on a normal linked list.) If you're tracking the length with an accumulator, returning the number of larger elements would be as simple as `length-index`.

One more possible bonus to using this approach is that `std::set.insert()` [is log(n) efficient already without a hint](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/), so efficiency is already in question.

Comment: `std::set` uses a balanced binary tree; it couldn't achieve O(log N) lookup and insert otherwise.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Fixed that. There were other data structures that use linked list, and I got confused. :3

Comment: How will we apply binary search on a linked list as we don't have random access ?

Comment: Argh, my mistake. You'd need to use a skip list, not a linked list. I just learned something new. >.> Edited the answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: And as it happens `vector` is awesomely good at minimising allocation, allowing for average O(1) append and generally excellent performance.

Comment: Indeed. As I said, *some cases*, i.e. where dynamic allocation needs to be avoided more than usual. (I'm working with a project that we need to attempt to avoid it altogether where necessary.) But, I agree that for most average situations, vector is fantastic.